# Firebase Help : Avoid New ID on new Push

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: firebase json tree]

Pushing Data Like This:

```
myDataRef.push({name : name, text: text});
```

I don't want every Push to create '-KGD************' entry. I want to add data anonymously, I want all data like this:

```
web>
    data>
        ran_name>                 //this being first push
            one : 1
            two : 2
        name : esjgnj             //this being second push
        text : gjnse              //this being third push
```

Comment: Use update instead of push. Or set.

Comment: Sounds like an answer Andre, especially if you also add a snippet of code. :-)

Comment: set will remove all data i added, creates new data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [Update()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/update.html) it won't generate a unique ID every time but just update the data at that location. Like this :

```
myDataRef.update({name : name, text: text});
```

Comment: then, how would you retrieve that? the value of 'name'

Comment: You should take some time to read the firebase [guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/). Almost everything is explaned there with example code.