# Angular-firebase. Data is not inserted correctly

Tags: angularjs, controller, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want my data to be inserted in firebase like so :

```
cities:{
    Tokyo:{
        name: "Tokyo, JP"
    }
    London:{
        name: "London, UK"
    }

    and so on...
```

I inserted some data manually from the online GUI : [cities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6EK0.jpg)

But unfortunately it gets inserted so : [minsk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BD2fd.jpg)

**My code**

the Firebase factory:

```
export default function CitiesFactory($firebaseArray, Firebase) {
    'ngInject';
    var ref = new Firebase("https://name.firebaseio.com/");
    return $firebaseArray(ref.child('cities'));
}
```

Controller (add function):

```
    $scope.addoras = function(city) {
        CitiesFactory.$add({
            city: {
                name: city
            }
        }).then(function(CitiesFactory) {
            var id = CitiesFactory.key();
            console.log('Added Contact ' + id);
            $scope.addorasmodel = '';

        });
    };
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845390/firebase-help-avoid-new-id-on-new-push/36846118#36846118

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use $add() it will generate a unique push id as it says in the [documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html).

If you want to avoid these unique id's you can use set() or update() ([Documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html))

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://name.firebaseio.com/");
ref.set({
    city: {
        name: city
    }
});

var ref = new Firebase("https://name.firebaseio.com/");
ref.update({
    city: {
        name: city
    }
});
```